# Disable Google Smart Lock in chrome password settings by password manager

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-smartlockpasswords

I installed truekey and dashlane password managers which disable the google smart lock.

if we go and check chrome://settings/passwords, it shows google smart lock feature in disabled state and says Truekey (or Dashlane) is controlling this setting.

I want to know how do they disable this setting without end user knowing about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True key does show a permission warning to "Change your privacy related settings".

It uses the chrome.privacy api: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/privacy

Add the "privacy" permission to the manifest.

Then, you can disable Chrome's password manager like this:

```
chrome.privacy.services.passwordSavingEnabled.get({}, function({ levelOfControl }) {
 if(levelOfControl == "controllable_by_this_extension") {
  chrome.privacy.services.passwordSavingEnabled.set({ value: true }, function() {
   if(chrome.runtime.lastError == null) {
    console.log("success")
   } else {
    console.log("error:", chrome.runtime.lastError)
} }) } })
```